# Not Null Constraint Failed - null=True already set

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am changing my register model so that there is a foreign key referencing a location. What I want to achieve, is to have a relationship where the Register model can have 0 to many locations.

Originally I set a manytomany field which I realised was a mistake as it gives each Register all of the locations in existence. I just want a subset for each Register.

My model now looks like:

```
class Register(AbstractBaseUser, models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='',blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='',blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=True)
    #Added 2nd May
    #locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    #3rd May change to foreign key
    locations = models.ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

The model referenced is:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    locationname = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='',blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    geolocation = models.ForeignKey(GeoLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

When I try to migrate I get the error below. I have ran makemigrations and if I run it again it states there are no changes.

"NOT NULL constraint failed: register_register.locations_id"

I have been searching other posts and it suggested adding the null=True argument which I have added, but I still get this error. I can't find any posts where this has been done and it still gives this error.

Comment: do you have data in the tables?

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes to both. If it’s a case of purging data first which Da Data needs to be deleted and is this managed through manage.py or only the admin console?

Comment: I have deleted all of the data in the database by using manage.py flush and it now seems to have migrated. Further testing is required though.

Can anyone advise on if it would have been the locations column causing the issue and on how to purge data from just one column?

In this instance all of the data was just junk test data so it was okay for me to delete the lot.

Answer (score 0):

Purging the data from the database using manage.py flush allowed me to re-migrate the projects.

I realised that I had made a mistake with the relationship and had the Foreign key on the wrong table, it needed to be on location so that was fundamentally the issue.